# Adding the 'log_not_found off;' config in nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, logging, kubernetes-ingress

I want to change my Kubernetes nginx ingress config to NOT log the "No such file or directory" errors.

I am not super familiar with nginx conf in general, I have edited some here and there but some parts still remain cryptic to me. I want this conf to only apply to one of the Ingress in my cluster : we will call it **media**.

To test it, I visit an URL and see in Grafana if the error is logged.

I tried several things :

- add the following to my Ingress resource:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
    location / {
      log_not_found off;
    }
```

-> Didn't work because the "/" location was duplicated, see error:

```
[emerg] duplicate location "/" in /tmp/nginx/nginx-cfg189799186:708
```

- I opened a shell to my nginx-controller pod and edited the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, in the block where there is my media Ingress conf. I added the `log_not_found off;` below in the `server` block, at the beginning (didn't work) and in the `location /` block (didn't work neither). I restarted nginx after the config updates.

BTW, it worked when I added the following in the Ingress ressource :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
    location /favicon.ico {
      log_not_found off;
    }
```

... but only for the favicon.ico path.

I won't use a ConfigMap to provide a nginx.conf since I read online that it will apply to all of my Ingress resources in the cluster

How to make it working for all paths ?